# Swift 3 - Limit TextField to alphanumeric (with whitespace and hypens)

Tags: swift, input, whitespace, textfield, alphanumeric

Want to limit Textfield input to only A-Z,a-z,0-9, " " and -. Currently have:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        if self.isNumericTextInput{
            let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
            let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
            if allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet) && returnFlag{
                return true
            } else{
                return false
            }

        } else{
            // Allow only alphanumerics, whitespace and hyphens
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to limit the text field to letter, numbers, and those few punctuation characters? You already know how to filter for numbers. The other is identical except for the character set.

Answer (score 8):

Though it's late to answer, but it might be useful to someone.

Swift 3:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    /// 1. replacementString is NOT empty means we are entering text or pasting text: perform the logic
    /// 2. replacementString is empty means we are deleting text: return true
    if string.characters.count > 0 {
        var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
        allowedCharacters.insert(charactersIn: " -") // "white space & hyphen" 

       let unwantedStr = string.trimmingCharacters(in: allowedCharacters)
       return unwantedStr.characters.count == 0
    }

    return true
}
```

Note: This will work for pasting strings into the text field as well. Pasted string will not be displayed in text field if it contains any unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

    let allowedCharacters = (self.isNumericTextInput
        ? CharacterSet.decimalDigits
        : CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 -"))

    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet) && returnFlag
}
```